# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: When I'll try to choose value in dropdown list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Select, but get an exception - ElementNotInteractableException.
How can i solve this issue?

```
    <select id="month0" class="custom-select" name="month0" aria-required="true" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: -9999px;" aria-invalid="true">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="Jan">January</option>
        <option value="Feb">February</option>
        <option value="Mar">March</option>
        <option value="Apr">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="Jun">June</option>
        <option value="Jul">July</option>
        <option value="Aug">August</option>
        <option value="Sep">September</option>
        <option value="Oct">October</option>
        <option value="Nov">November</option>
        <option value="Dec">December</option>
</select>
<span id="month0-button" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all errorInput" tabindex="0" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="month0-menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-required="true" style="width: 99px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-5" aria-labelledby="month0-label ui-id-5 month0-required" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="month0-error">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"/>
        <span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Month</span>
</span>
<span id="month0-required" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity:0; position:absolute; left:-9999px">Required</span>
```

My code:

```
Select selectElement = new Select(monthDropDown);
selectElement.selectByVisibleText(month);
//or selectElement.selectByValue(month)  - don't working too
//or selectElement.selectByIndex("2")    - don't working too
```

Locators used:

```
@FindBy(id = "month0")
WebElement monthDropDown;

@FindBy(id = "day0")
WebElement dayDropDown;

@FindBy(id = "year0")
WebElement yearDropDown;
```

Comment: Try to use click instead. Driver.findElement => element.click

Comment: What else have you tried? You didn't include the locators used or what you are looking for. Also, screenshots of the UI is fine but you should always post the HTML and format it as code here. Screenshots will eventually be gone rendering this question less useful.

Answer (score 0):

What is '`month`' in your code?

For using `selectByIndex()`

use below code. There seems to be a typo with your code.

```
selectElement.selectByIndex(2);
```

Comment: month - this is a String. selectElement.selectByIndex(2) - don't help

Comment: @Vadim - what is its value? Did selectByIndex() solve your issue?